# How Google Wear install app from Google Play

Tags: applications, google-play-store, android-wear

I got to know that when you try to install any Android mobile app which also have Android Wear app, then Google Play automatically push the build to Android Wear device.

I am not sure whether is it right or wrong. Please help how this flow works.

Do we have Gmail app in Android Wear like in Android phone?

Comment: It'd be easier to give a useful answer if you add a little background to your question. "How does it work?" covers a lot of ground, so what in particular are you trying to understand? What's the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the below is *generic* details. OEMs have their own Android Wear apps, just as an example [Smart Connect from Sony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware&hl=en)

According to [this article](http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-launch-apps-on-android-wear/):

> When you install an Android app that also has an Android Wear app, the app is automatically installed on your watch.

The watch connects and starts downloading apps using the phone’s internet connection. You need to have the [Android Wear App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app&hl=en) installed on the phone to enable this.

---

As for Gmail, yes you can use it on a Smart Watch.

[See here for details](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6057269?hl=en). You can do the following with Gmail in Android Wear:

**Read email**

Your new email will show up in a Gmail card. Touch the card to expand the message. If the message is long, you might have to tap to expand it multiple times.

If you have multiple messages, you’ll see a bar at the bottom of the card that shows how many messages you have. Touch the bar to see the rest of your messages.

You’ll get Gmail cards if you get Gmail notifications on your phone. [Learn more about how notifications work on Android Wear](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056843).

**Reply to an email**

When you get a new email, you can read and reply by going to the Gmail card. Swipe ← to the left until you see the “reply” action. You will have to touch to reply. You can’t use a voice command like “reply.”

- If your watch’s screen is dimmed, touch it to wake up your screen first.
- Your Gmail message will show up in a card. Touch the message you want to reply to.
- Swipe ← to the left until you see Reply.
- Touch Reply.
- Say your message. Your message will send automatically.

  - Keep in mind, you can’t edit what you said after this point. If you want to change or cancel your message, you’ll have one second to press Cancel.

**Send an email**
You can speak to your watch to send an email to a contact, or say the email address.

- If your watch’s screen is dimmed, touch it to wake up your screen first.
- Say “Ok Google.” You’ll see a white screen with a red “g.”
- Say the following: “Send email to Alex Jones that I’m looking forward to dinner tomorrow.”

**Archive an email**

You can archive an email right from your watch.

- If your watch's screen is dimmed, touch it to wake up your screen
  first.
- Your Gmail message will show up in a card. Touch the
  message you want to archive.
- Swipe ← to left until you see
  Archive.
- Touch Archive.
- Your message will be archived.

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps sync. only specific ones for the android wear.

for email i use this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearmail but you can also tell your watch to send an email via voice commands. "messenger for wear" also does SMS text messages. its got its own built in keyboard as well as letting you give voice commands.

simple answer is to make sure the app you install supports wear first.

and to answer the first question you can go into the google wear app and tap the sync button somewhere in the menu to manually sync. though should do automatcally